# Model architecture object detection where entire image context and nearby objects are important to accurate prediction

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection

I'm working on a model to classify multiple extremely similar looking objects in a single image. A simple object detection model works ok but the issue is that I'm classifying similar looking object from aerial imagery. Think houses in a neighborhood that you want to match to an address. So the way a person would classify would be to pull up a satellite image and use it as a reference and learn the spatial relationships between the various houses to label them. I'm wondering if there are better models out there that will take the entire image context and the spatial relationships of the objects in the image in account when making a prediction. I can easily create an object detection model to classify the universe of objects (houses) first and then do a custom image classification model second. I was considering an approach like this: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1812/1812.00291.pdf

Are there any other techniques I should be looking at? Since the relationships between these objects is so consistent it seems like a problem that should be very easy to solve with ML.